# Python Hangman - Loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to write a function to use to play hangman, and everything is working perfectly except for the fact that the function doesn't recognize when the game has been won.

---EDIT---

here is my revised code

```
def hangman():
    word = choose_word(wordlist)
    guessed_word = len(word)*['_']
    guesses = 10
    available_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    guessed_letters = ""
    letters_correct = 0
    print "Welcome to the game, Hangman!"
    print "I am thinking of a word that is", len(word), "letters long."
    print "Available letters:", available_letters
    print "You have", guesses, "guesses."
    while letters_correct != len(word):
        guess = raw_input("enter your guess:")
        if len(guess)==1 and guess.isalpha():
            if guessed_letters.find(guess) != -1:
                print "You already picked", guess
            else:
                guessed_letters = guessed_letters + guess
                index1 = word.find(guess)
                if  index1 == -1:
                    print "The letter",guess,"is not in the word", ' '.join(guessed_word)
                    guesses = guesses - 1
                    print "You have", guesses, "guesses left."
                    if guesses == 0:
                        return "You are out of guesses. You lose. The word was "+ word + "."
                    available_letters = available_letters.replace(guess, '')
                    print "Available letters:", available_letters
                else:
                    letters_correct = letters_correct + word.count(guess)
                    print"The letter", guess, "is in the word."
                    for i in range(len(word)):
                        if guess == word[i]:
                            guessed_word[i] = guess
                            print ' '.join(guessed_word)
                            if letters_correct != len(word):
                                print "You have", guesses, "guesses left."
                                available_letters = available_letters.replace(guess, '')
                                print "Available letters:", available_letters
                            elif guesses <= 0:
                                return "You are out of guesses. You lose. The word was "+ word + "."
        else:
            print "Please guess a single letter in the alphabet."
    if letters_correct == len(word):
        return "Congratualations! You figured out that the word is "+ word
```

Comment: My first word of guidance would be "functional decomposition." Instead of writing the whole program in one function, write it in multiple functions. Then you can fully test each sub-function, which makes problem determination much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the problem with the hangman game loop not terminating is with the letters_correct counter variable that the game while loop checks.

```
while letters_correct != len(word):
```

Let's say the word is **banana** and I guess the letter **a**

the branch in your code that handles a correct guess begins with this line:

```
letters_correct = letters_correct + 1
```

In the case of my word **banana** and guess **a** then the letters_correct variable should be *incremented three times*. Now if i guess **n** the letters_correct should be *incremented twice*.

In your current implementation guessing in the order I did would only increment letters_correct twice (2), when it should be 5. So, *when increasing letters_count increment it the number of times guess appears in word*.

```
letters_count = letters_count + word.count(guess)
```

That way on the game loop check the letters_count variable would actually be able to reach the length of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the situation where your word has multiple of the same letter?

Currently you only increment letters_correct once if the user guesses correctly. If you increment the number of correct letters once per occurrence, it should work.